# AND syntax in outer join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

this is a small piece of a much larger query that I have discovered is a problem.

I'm trying to add a filter to my outer join in addition to the primary key.  The problem is that I'm receiving results that have an StatusCode other than 0 or 1, as if it is ignoring the filter.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products P
LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderDetails OD ON OD.SkuNum = P.SkuNum
LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderHeader OH ON (OD.ShipmentNum = OH.ShipmentNum
                               AND (OH.StatusCode = 0 OR OH.StatusCode = 1))
WHERE P.SkuNum = XXXX
```

Note that if I put that statement (OH.StatusCode = 0 OR OH.StatusCode = 1) in the where clause it filters the entire result set by that criteria which is not what I want either.

For this join in plain english, I'm trying to say "Give me all products and other *stuff not listed here*. If there are any shipments for this product, give me all the details for them where the shipment has a status of 1 or 0"

Is my syntax wrong or am I missing something?  Thanks.

Edit:  Updated the query to include products to make it clearer what I'm looking for and fixed a transposition error.

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting it, but shouldnt you turn this around? As in OrderHeader LEFT JOIN OrderDetails? You always have a header, but only sometimes the details, right?

Comment: Do you have a typo in your filter? byStatusCode is not the same as StatusCode

Comment: @rickythefox: easier to just change `LEFT` to `RIGHT`.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify, the left join is because this is part of a small query where I get a list of all products, regardless of whether or not that are part of an order.  The OrderDetails part is normally in a left join as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you will always have an OrderHeader for a given OrderDetail, but you might not have one with status 0, 1.

By doing a left join, you are getting all for that particular Sku, and then if the order header doesn't have status 0, 1, those columns will be `NULL`.

I would think you want an **INNER JOIN**.  But then that would usually be equivalent to putting everything in the **WHERE**, so I'm note sure you're fully describing what you want to get here.

After seeing your edit, try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products P
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT OD.SkuNum, OD.ShipmentNum, etc.
    FROM OrderDetails OD
    INNER JOIN OrderHeader OH
        ON OD.ShipmentNum = OH.ShipmentNum
            AND (OH.StatusCode = 0 OR OH.StatusCode = 1)
) AS Orders ON Orders.SkuNum = P.SkuNum
WHERE P.SkuNum = XXXX
```

Comment: Yes I do get NULLs, in my full query (which is too large to post here) I actually am doing SUMs and eliminating NULLs.  I essentially just pulled the part of the larger query out and pasted it here because it is the source of the problem.  The StatusCode filter is not applying to the join.

Comment: that did the trick.  It's essentially like separating out the sub-query which was going to be my fall-back plan.  This is a more elegant way of including it in the original query.  Thanks!

Comment: @TerryR You can make this a little slicker with a RIGHT JOIN.  But I don't normally bother.  The optimizer is going to produce the same execution plan and reading left to right is better.

Comment: You can also do the same by re-ordering the `ON` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

By doing a left join, you are saying you want all order details where skunum = xxxx regardless on if there is any matches in the order header table.

Based on your query and plain english description, to me it sounds like you want an inner join.  But maybe I don't understand enough or have enough information.  The inner join would only return all of the order details where the shipment has a status of 1 or 0 and the skunum matches.

Comment: Sorry I updated the query it may be clearer now that an inner join is not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a derived table here.

By placing the `ON OD.SkuNum = P.SkuNum` clause last the `LEFT JOIN` on Products logically happens last.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Products P
       LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderDetails OD
                       INNER JOIN OrderHeader OH
                         ON OD.ShipmentNum = OH.ShipmentNum
                            AND OH.StatusCode IN ( 0, 1 )
         ON OD.SkuNum = P.SkuNum
WHERE  P.SkuNum = 'XXXX'
```

Comment: Wow, in all my years of SQL I've never tried that - it's not terribly readable, unfortunately.  I guess you could add some parentheses, but then it would look like some of those funky ones Access used to generate.

Comment: @Cade - Yes definitely not something that appears to be in common use. [Itzik Ben Gan wrote an article on this here](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/take-control-of-joins) although there were some [additional clarifications/corrections to that here](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/letters-february-2004) As you say in your answer this would be achieved more easily with a `right join`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM OrderHeader OH
LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderDetails OD ON OD.ShipmentNum = OH.ShipmentNum AND OD.SkuNum = XXXX
WHERE OH.StatusCode IN (0, 1)
```

Your statement in plain english seems to idicate that you're looking for a specific shipment.  You might want to add a shipmentnum to the where clause.

Comment: No this is not what I'm looking for as it will filter the entire query - I did mention this not sure if it was clear.  My recent edit may help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Products P
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT  OD.*
            FROM    OrderHeader OH
                    INNER JOIN OrderDetails OD
                        ON OH.ShipmentNum = OD.ShipmentNum
            WHERE   OH.StatusCode IN (0,1)
        ) as orders    
            ON P.SkuNum = orders.SkuNum
WHERE    P.SkuNum = XXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products P
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  ( OrderDetails OD 
     INNER JOIN OrderHeader OH ON (OD.ShipmentNum = OH.ShipmentNum
                               AND (OH.StatusCode = 0 OR OH.StatusCode = 1))
  ) ON OD.SkuNum = P.SkuNum
WHERE P.SkuNum = XXXX
```