# Inner join 3 tables - show rows for ID that isn't found in other tables

Tags: sql, select, join

Hello I have this Inner join of 3 tables

```
SELECT ADDRESS.NAME, ADDRESS.SURNAME, ADDRESS.PLACE,ADDRESS.TOTAL_COST_YEAR, ADDRESS.AREA, ISNULL(SUM(RENT.TO_PAY), 0) AS SumToPay, ISNULL(SUM(ORDER.AMOUNT), 0) AS SumPaid FROM ORDER
INNER JOIN ADDRESS
ON ADDRESS.IDadresa=ORDER.IDadresa
INNER JOIN RENT
on RENT.IDadresa = ORDER.IDadresa
GROUP BY ADDRESS.NAME, ADDRESS.SURNAME,ADDRESS.PLACE,ADDRESS.TOTAL_COST_YEAR,ADDRESS.AREA
```

It works well but sometimes values which are found under `IDadresa` in table `ADDRESS` doesn't containg any records in other tables but I still need the rows from `ADDRESSES` to be shown.

I think it is because there isn't any record for that ID in columns RENT and ORDER. May someone please help me improve this code ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use `left outer join` instead of `inner join` for both the joins.  You want to keep everything in the `address` table, so make that the first table in the sequence and make all the joins `left outer join`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for comment, should I use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in both `JOINS` ? When I do I have sitll same results.

Comment: right join between order and adress, left join between address and rent

Comment: @wxyz thank you! Works well, please post it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: See [this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need all Address rows everytime just use `right join` between order and adress, `left join` between address and rent

Comment: Why do you recommend right join instead of reordering the tables to get all left joins? I think you should help beginners avoid right joins.

Answer (score 2):

The following should provide the expected results:

```
SELECT a.NAME, a.SURNAME, a.PLACE,a.TOTAL_COST_YEAR, a.AREA, ISNULL(SUM(RENT.TO_PAY), 0) AS SumToPay, ISNULL(SUM(ORDER.AMOUNT), 0) AS SumPaid FROM ORDER
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS a
    ON a.IDadresa=ORDER.IDadresa
RIGHT OUTER JOIN RENT
    ON RENT.IDadresa = ORDER.IDadresa
GROUP BY a.NAME, a.SURNAME,a.PLACE,a.TOTAL_COST_YEAR,a.AREA
```

Comment: Why do you recommend right join instead of reordering the tables to get all left joins? I think you should help beginners avoid right joins.

Comment: @ErikE .. I would be curious to read about the benefits of Left over Right joins.  Please provide a reference, as a quick search seems to agree with the following SO link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358084/which-is-better-left-outer-join-or-right-outer-join

Comment: Please clarify: are you expressing lack of agreement with my point, or lack of understanding of it?

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand the benefits of LEFT over RIGHT joins.  After your initial comment, I searched the web some to find a resource that would explain, but mostly found that left vs. right was a matter of preference (hence the SO article).  I would be interested to review a link that would explain.

Comment: Because using only left joins expresses intent more clearly to junior developers and confuses them less, and there is no real benefit to miximg or using right joins. Furthermore, left joins put the more important tables first in the text, speeding comprehension when scanning.

Comment: And one more compelling reason all by itself: when the outer join needs to be filtered in the join itself (which almost always is on the outer table), you end up with the situation where a condition on a table is far from the table reference! That is a big pitfall worth avoiding. If you don't know what I mean,  please say so.