# Table A Left Outer JOIN Table B VS Table B Right Outer JOIN A

Tags: sql, left-join, outer-join, right-join

Is `TABLE A LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE B` the same as `TABLE B RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE A` in in terms of output and performance?

(Regardless of data content and size of table A, and table B)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is better.. left outer join or right outer join?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358084/which-is-better-left-outer-join-or-right-outer-join)

Answer (score 1):

Yes those are equivalent. Left join is generally preferred because it is the most commonly used, so the meaning is more immediately clear.